# Why Login Button don't works in Unity Hub

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have downloaded unity hub recently, everything work fine until i press the sign in or creat account button, nothing happen and i just stuck there, i click these button many time
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKSPQ.jpg)

i have tried download the editor without unity hub but then the editor need an activation file (.ulf file)
i did it mannually but when i click the editor it just take me to unity hub and nothing happen again

Comment: Are you behind a company proxy server? Ive had the same problem with that

Comment: no i am just a student trying to make a game with unity

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - clicking on the button didn't do anything. This is on Windows 10.

My workaround was to run Unity Hub as administrator - right click on the Desktop shortcut (after closing the hub from the system tray menu), and choose 'Run as administrator'.

Answer (score 0):

does not work, buttons do not respond to anything. Tried on different versions of Unity Hub

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something like this as well on Fedora 35. I think I've got a handle on it, though I can't fully explain the details of it.

Like with you, Unity Hub would not open any browser links. On top of "Sign In" and "Create Account", the following didn't work for example:

- "Go to Unity Dashboard"
- "Tray Iron -> Troubleshooting -> View Hub Release Notes"
- "Tray Icon -> Troubleshooting -> View Hub Documentation"
- "Tray Icon -> Troubleshooting -> View Log Folder" (This one wasn't even a browser)
- "Community -> Any Link"

Anywho, my technique to work around this now is:

1. Make sure that any broken Unity Hub instances are closed.
2. Open a `unityhub://` link in your browser. In Firefox, I would enter in junk like just `unityhub://` or `unityhub://1234`
3. The instance of Unity Hub that spawns up will be able to open links.

   - There will be a small pop-up griping about an unknown version if you gave it something bogus like I did, but it's easily dismissed.

I'm still a bit unclear on what's different between the two, but now that it's working I'm not super-inclined to keep digging.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. After clicking on "Sign in," the Unity Hub takes me to a blank page. Uninstalling Unity and then opening Unity by itself with a manual license helped me bypass the Unity Hub issue.

Answer (score 0):

just set any browser as a default browser and try again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to run Unity Hub in WSL. Once I installed a browser in WSL, the Unity Hub links started working.